# Calculate the maximum number of the three in javascript

Tags: javascript, input, max, alert, negative-number

This is my code, and it works, but only with positive numbers. If I write nothing into the input it considers as value 0, and this is a problem if I have only one or two negative numbers.

```js
function Calculeaza() {
    var a = document.getElementById('input1').value;
    var b = document.getElementById('input2').value;
    var c = document.getElementById('input3').value;
    var max = 0;

    var max = Math.max(a, b, c);

    if (a == '' && b == '' && c == '') {
        max = 'Input at least one number';
    }
    alert(max);
}
```

I tried to take as input only one negative number, and I expect to alert that as the maximum, but in the Alert I get 0 as an answer.

Comment: For the next time: please take care on code identation. This improves the readability of code for other users.

Comment: "one negative number, and I expect to alert that as the maximum" - ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why you are getting 0 as the maximum value when you enter a negative number is that Math.max() function considers an empty string or any non-numeric input as 0. To handle negative numbers properly, you can modify your code to check if the input values are valid numbers using isNaN() function before calculating the maximum value.

Here's an updated code snippet that checks for valid input values and considers negative numbers as the maximum value:

```
  var a = parseFloat(document.getElementById("input1").value);
  var b = parseFloat(document.getElementById("input2").value);
  var c = parseFloat(document.getElementById("input3").value);
  var max = -Infinity;

  if (isNaN(a) && isNaN(b) && isNaN(c)) {
    max = "Input at least one number";
  } else {
    if (!isNaN(a) && a > max) {
      max = a;
    }
    if (!isNaN(b) && b > max) {
      max = b;
    }
    if (!isNaN(c) && c > max) {
      max = c;
    }
  }
  
  alert(max);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
var input1 = '';
var input2 = '';
var input3 = '';

var inputs = [input1, input2, input3];

var numbers = [];
for (var index in inputs) {
  if (inputs[index] !== '') {
    numbers.push(parseInt(inputs[index]));
  }
}

if (numbers.length === 0) {
  alert('Input at least one number')
} else {
  alert(Math.max(numbers));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This code will likely output 0 in the case where all 3 fields are empty, so I advise you to parse the Numbers before proceeding further.

```js
 function Calculeaza()
  {
    var a = document.getElementById("input1").value;
    var b = document.getElementById("input2").value;
    var c = document.getElementById ("input3").value;
    var max=0;

    // parse to int and remove any NaN, 0s
    const inputs = [a, b, c].map(ip => Number.parseInt(ip)).filter(e => e);
    
    var max = Math.max (inputs); 
    
    if (a=='' && b=='' && c=='') {
        max=("Input at least one number");
    }
    alert(max);    
  }
```

Comment: I got the same problem. Output 0 when one of the fields is empty.

Answer (score -1):

Here is it:

```
let max=Number.MIN_VALUE;
if(a>max) max=a;
if(b>max) max=b;
if(c>max) max=c;
```

Comment: Not a good answer at all: `Number.MIN_VALUE` represents the smallest positive number representable in JS. That being said, if `a`, `b` or c is a negative number, your code would provide a wrong answer.

Comment: Now I get 5e-324 as max.

Comment: use `Number.NEGATIVE_INFINITY` instead

Comment: Or `let max = a; if(b>max) max=b; if(c>max) max=c;` to avoid `Number.NEGATIVE_INFINITY`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).